# How remove or set decimal digit with polar area apex chart

Tags: angular, angular-material, apexcharts

How remove or decimal digit with polar area apex chart

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgtjQ.png)

I want to 2 decimal digit or remove this number to the graph

Polar area Apex Chart

This is my source code

```
this.duChartOptions2 = {
series:  [1,2,4],
chart: {
  type: "polarArea"
},
labels: [a,b,c],
stroke: {
  colors: ["#fff"]
},
fill: {
  opacity: 0.8
},
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      chart: {
        width: 200
      },
      legend: {
        position: "bottom"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

};

Answer (score 4):

Here, this is how you can round numbers on the y axis

```
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: (value) => {
          return value.toFixed(1)
        },
      }
    },
```